# XGboost - Grid search does not work correctly

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, grid-search

My Xgboost regressor without parameterization has `64.5` R2

When I manually add hyperparameters as below, I get `66.4` R2

```
xgb1 = XGBRegressor(
learning_rate=0.09,
max_depth=4,
min_child_weight=2,
subsample=0.7
)
```

However, when I do grid search, entering hyperparameters within the range of those that I have selected manually -  R2 is only `63`

Grid search:

```
xgb1 = XGBRegressor()

parameters = {'learning_rate': [0.09, 0.1, 0.2], 
              'min_child_weight':[1, 2, 3], 
              'gamma':[0, .1],
              'subsample':[.7, .8, .9, 1],
              'colsample_bytree':[.8, .9, 1], 
              'max_depth': [3, 4, 5], 
              'n_estimators': [100, 120, 200] }

xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb1,
                        parameters,
                        cv = 5,
                        n_jobs = -1,
                        verbose=True)

xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(xgb_grid.best_score_)
print(xgb_grid.best_params_)
```

As you can see in the 'parameters' are the values ​​that I selected manually. Grid search chooses completely different parameters that give 
worse than default parameters. 
It's not the first time I'm in a situation where manual parameterization gives better results than Grid search. What could be the reason for this?

Best parameters and score:

```
0.6384582336141522
{'colsample_bytree': 0.8, 'gamma': 0.1, 'learning_rate': 0.2, 'max_depth': 4, 'min_child_weight': 3, 'n_estimators': 120, 'subsample': 0.9}
```

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what your issue is - that the performance is not good, or that grid search does not use the parameters you provide? Your title implies the first, while your text the second. If it is the second, please also provide the parameters finally chosen by the process.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem here.

All the parameters you listed in your second code snippet are present in the `parameters` dictionary.

Also, you will always get slightly different results on every run, since there is some degree of randomness involved, due to the subsampling, column sampling, etc. If you want to get the same result every time you use the same set of parameters, then initialize the regressor with a random state set to an integer value: `XGBRegressor(random_state=42)`.

Comment: random state is set and the result is always the same. - 66.4 for Grid search it always comes out 63.3. for default parameters - 64.5

Comment: For grid search, the data is split into 5 sets in total with 1 set being left out of the training process for validation (if `cv=5`). Have you tried, using only 80% of the data for the manual approach and validating it on the remaining 20%?